# Iron Router Action vs OnBeforeAction

Tags: meteor, iron-router

What is the difference between iron:router's `action` vs `onBeforeAction`. Initially my guess would be that action is a route hook that is constantly active, whereas `onBeforeAction` is only performed before the route is rendered. Also how would I describe a global action for all of the routes. `Router.onBeforeAction` works so that I can globally define a hook for all routes, however I cannot use `Router.action` the same way. Maybe I am just misunderstanding what `action` is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

action is meant to be used in Route Controllers for specific templates.

You need to notice that is optional because the default action's behavior is to render the route along with it's layout and regions automatically.
So if you want to alter the default behavior when using route controllers  you could do something like this:

```
this.PostAdController = RouteController.extend({

  'template' : 'InsertPostTemplate',
  'subscriptions' : function(){ /* subs here */ },

  'action'   : function(){
    // this could be empty in most cases, but:
    if (this.ready()){ this.render(); } else { this.render('Loading'); }
  }


});
```

So with that code you render the Loading template in case the subscriptions are not ready.